# Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 6 to TIMESTAMP

Tags: hibernate

I am using criteria API to get rows from MySQL database. There are some rows where timestamp field has value '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

I have place this line in my hibernate configuration

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>
```

But still i do not get a Object with timestamp set to null instead an exception is shown

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 6     to TIMESTAMP
```

If i write te jdbc url appended with zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull , it might work
What needs to be done to return nulls in place zero datetime values using only hibernat e configuration properties?

Comment: I would recommend to replace the '0000-00-00 00:00:00' with NULLs right in your database. In most cases it makes sense.

Comment: @curandero i cannot edit the database as i will have only select privilege